# Using grep to get the rows of a dataframe, instead of the row number

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I am trying to make a sub dataframe based on the already existing dataframe. My sub dataframe is being filled with the number of the row instead of the row itself.

```
rates = read.csv("file.txt")
genes = unique(gsub('_[0-9]+', '', rates[,1]))
for (k in unique(gsub('_[0-9]+', '', rates[,1])) ){
        sub = print(grep(k, rates[,1]), value=T)
        sub
}
```

file.txt

```
clothing,freq,temp
coat_1,0.3,10
coat_1,0.9,0
coat_1,0.1,20
coat_2,0.5,20
coat_2,0.3,15
coat_2,0.1,5
scarf,0.4,30
scarf,0.2,20
scarf,0.1,10
```

This is what is currently output

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
[1] 7 8 9
```

I would like something like this instead

```
  clothing freq temp
1   coat_1  0.3   10
2   coat_1  0.9    0
3   coat_1  0.1   20
4   coat_2  0.5   20
5   coat_2  0.3   15
6   coat_2  0.1    5

  clothing freq temp
1    scarf  0.4   30
2    scarf  0.2   20
3    scarf  0.1   10
```

Comment: You could just do `split(rates, rates$clothing == "scarf")`

Comment: Try this instead in the loop: `sub = print(rates[grep(k, rates[,1]),] )`

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e , that did it

Answer (score 1):

```
 rates <- read.csv("file.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 rates
#  clothing freq temp
# 1   coat_1  0.3   10
# 2   coat_1  0.9    0
# 3   coat_1  0.1   20
# 4   coat_2  0.5   20
# 5   coat_2  0.3   15
# 6   coat_2  0.1    5
# 7    scarf  0.4   30
# 8    scarf  0.2   20
# 9    scarf  0.1   10

 rates[rates$clothing != "scarf",]
#  clothing freq temp
# 1   coat_1  0.3   10
# 2   coat_1  0.9    0
# 3   coat_1  0.1   20
# 4   coat_2  0.5   20
# 5   coat_2  0.3   15
# 6   coat_2  0.1    5
rates[rates$clothing == "scarf",]
#  clothing freq temp
#7    scarf  0.4   30
#8    scarf  0.2   20
#9    scarf  0.1   10
```